# Using ORDER BY ... LIMIT 20; makes query extremely slow

Tags: mysql

I'm looking into an issue with slow queries, and I can't figure out why using LIMIT 20 on this query makes it a factor 100 slower.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.eventid,e.clock,e.ns,e.objectid,e.acknowledged,er1.r_eventid 
FROM events e JOIN event_recovery er1 ON er1.eventid=e.eventid 
WHERE e.source='0' AND e.object='0' AND e.objectid='115779' 
      AND e.eventid<='65535859' AND e.value='1' 
ORDER BY e.eventid 
LIMIT 20;
```

---

EXPLAIN:

**Without LIMIT 20:**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT e.eventid... ORDER BY e.eventid;
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys             | key      | key_len | ref                     | rows  | Extra                                                               |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ref    | PRIMARY,events_1,events_2 | events_1 | 16      | const,const,const       | 15792 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | er1   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                   | PRIMARY  | 8       | zabbix_server.e.eventid |     1 |                                                                     |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

(4256 rows in set (0.050 sec) when executed without EXPLAIN)

**With LIMIT 20:**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT e.eventid... ORDER BY e.eventid LIMIT 20;
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+---------+------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys             | key     | key_len | ref                     | rows    | Extra                        |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+---------+------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | e     | range  | PRIMARY,events_1,events_2 | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL                    | 2969589 | Using where; Using temporary |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | er1   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                   | PRIMARY | 8       | zabbix_server.e.eventid |       1 |                              |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+---------+------------------------------+
```

(20 rows in set (9.269 sec) when executed without EXPLAIN)

---

Why is it not using the keys for the LIMIT 20?

I'm using MariaDB 10.3.11 on Debian 9

**EDIT:**
Forcing it to use the INDEX makes it fast, but why doesn't the MySQL optimizer realise this?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT e.eventid,e.clock,e.ns,e.objectid,e.acknowledged,er1.r_eventid FROM events e USE INDEX (events_1) JOIN event_recovery er1 ON er1.eventid=e.eventid WHERE e.source='0' AND e.object='0' AND e.objectid='115779' AND e.eventid<='65535859' AND e.value='1' ORDER BY e.eventid LIMIT 20;
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref                     | rows  | Extra                                                               |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ref    | events_1      | events_1 | 16      | const,const,const       | 15820 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | er1   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 8       | zabbix_server.e.eventid |     1 |                                                                     |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I think it's well explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144723/mysql-very-simple-select-id-order-by-limit-will-not-use-index-as-expected

Comment: See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747871/why-is-mysql-slow-when-using-limit-in-my-query

Comment: Incidentally, be wary of wrapping integers in inverted commas.

Comment: @AlexandreJuma I still fail to understand why the LIMIT 20 makes it so slow, because the only thing different is that it will only show the first 20 results from my query. If you just grab the first 20 rows of the query without LIMIT 20 it will be exactly the same. The reason why the LIMIT is there is because I only need 20 results and it would otherwise cause way too much network I/O from the DB server

Comment: have you simply tried to enclose the limit query on top of your performant subquery?

Comment: Do you really need `DISTINCT`? If you could avoid the DISTINCT modifier the query can become much faster. But this can be a question change...

Comment: @TheImpaler The DISTINCT is needed yeah, it does save some time but as long as it uses the index its minimal.

Comment: @AlexandreJuma That would require changing the software (can't easily change the query itself), while I'm sure this is a MySQL optimizer issue. Adding "USE INDEX (events_1)" as a way to force the index, it actually becomes as fast as the non LIMIT 20; query. For some reason it just decides not to use the index